# Complicated Conditional

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a set of instruction at the top of my page:

```
    <div class="instructions">
        <div id="step1" class="step"><span class="step_active">1</span><span class="step_title_active">General Info</span></div>
        <div id="step2" class="step"><span class="step_next">2</span><span class="step_title">Select Contact</span></div>
        <div id="step3" class="step"><span class="step_next">3</span><span class="step_title">Log Details</span></div>
    </div>
```

I have a form that reveals itself as conditions are met. 
The first condition being that both select boxes must have options selected, before the next part appears.

```
<script>
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function () {
    $("#test").hide();
    $("#comType, #comDirection").bind('change', function () {
        // show the button if they both have a value
        if ($("#comType").val().length > 1 && $("#comDirection").val().length > 1) {
            $("#test").fadeIn();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

How can I change the classes in #step1 #step2 so that when the above conditions are met, they appear as:

```
   <div id="step1" class="step"><span class="step_complete">1</span><span class="step_title">General Info</span></div>
    <div id="step2" class="step"><span class="step_active">2</span><span class="step_title_active">Select Contact</span></div>
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Just trying to switch the the span classes inside div #step1 and #step2 when the js conditions are met. #Step1 would have #Step2 classes applied to the inner spans, and #step2 would have #Step1 classs. This is basically going to be a breadcrumb like navigation for the form, highlighting the step you are on.

Comment: In the post, it's currently set that step 1 appears to be active.

Comment: fiddle? demo? something to go on...

Comment: @Mark try to use addClass and removeClass of jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) & [removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) property of jQuery.

Try this:

```
if ($("#comType").val().length > 1 && $("#comDirection").val().length > 1) {
    $("#test").fadeIn();
    $("#step1").children("span").removeClass("step_active").addClass("step_complete");
    $("#step2").children("span").removeClass("step_next").addClass("step_active");
    $("#step1").children("span").next("span").removeClass("step_title_active").addClass("step_title");
    $("#step2").children("span").next("span").removeClass("step_title").addClass("step_title_active");   
}
```

Comment: `$("#step1").children("span")` can be written `$("#step1>span")`

Comment: @ThierryJ. $("#step1>span") traverse to all the child elements and here only required to traverse exactly first child element.